# How to declare and compare array variable from other selected variable

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

and i want to compare some values from an array with the ones from variable two

```
email = two[gmail.com, yahoo.com]; // how to type this correctly
```

and after compare the email variable with a value inserted by the user and send alert('We don't accept free e-mail) if user had inserted one of the values from the array.

```
if email = 0 // did not found any of the values listed in email = then return true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
function validateEmail() {
    var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
    if (["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"].indexOf(two) != -1) {
        alert("We don't accept free e-mail");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This makes a function called `validateEmail`.  It gets your `email` element, and checks the fixed array to see if it includes that element.  If it does, it sends your alert and returns false, otherwise it returns true.

A few attempts at guessing what you want instead of what you asked for:

First of all, you probably want the array to be a variable of its own.  This is just generally a good practice, and makes it easier for you to modify the array - or create it somewhere else.

```
var badEmails = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"];
if (badEmails.indexOf(two) != -1) {
```

More importantly, you may want to check against the whole email address entered by the user.  If `two` is a standard email, your function gets slightly more complex:

```
function validateEmail() {
    var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var badEmails = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"];
    for (var bad in badEmails) {
        if (two.indexOf(bad) != -1) {
            alert("We don't accept free e-mail");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have an unescaped apos in the alert string

Comment: Perfect answer now +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

To find out if the email entered by the user is in your blacklist:

```
var blacklist = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"]
```

then use the [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) to see if there's a match between user input and blacklist:

```
if (blacklist.indexOf(userInput) == -1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the text field contains only the domain part of the email (like "gmail.com" or yahoo.com), not the entire address.

```
var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
var forbidden = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"];

var found = forbidden.indexOf(two );
if(found > -1)
{
    alert("We don't accept free e-mail");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Scott Mermelstein's answer is good. I would only add that it's a good practice in JavaScript to avoid `!=` and `==` since they can sometimes throw false positives. It's better to be in the habit of using `!==` and `===` since they don't allow type coercion.

That said, locating a string within an array is easy when you have the `.indexOf` method. However, that method was implemented in 1.6 so IE6 and IE7 won't be able to use it.  Not sure about IE8 exactly.

If you're worried about those browsers, you can either implement the polyfill found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or write a function like this:

```
function indexOf(arr, str) {
  if (typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === 'function') {
    return arr.indexOf(str);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    if (arr[i] === str) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This function will return the index of the string inside the array or `-1` if it is not inside the array.